# geetest captcha v4 bypass

Tags: captcha, 2captcha

I use service to solve geetest v4 captcha which give me data like this:

```
{"captcha_id":"e392e1d7fd421dc63325744d5a2b9c73",
"lot_number":"1eab0ba51f5b4d93b167dda4cdfff4ac",
"pass_token":"51280f9098291add638370e4d4efc3b2f18f5fae3e1576b252b85578a0ab71ae",
"gen_time":"1650807025",
"captcha_output":"-_rFSA3yFzyq5GepVVUs6WI6ofv6COOyH28KAcnCl39v1xa_Sy_GlJfN_j3XbsBrOPBflEdQXlN8-vAT3QCpHwFcgVTEdgRMnLt4hG-I3CB4bfx9rJjzJWvphG3vmNMRDmY7RHXd1Obbp6vmAh_oqbC5PfEzk2IxGwjrml5Bx2AqcLB-jtB3O957AcvuDuSl"}
```

What should I do next? Where should I send this data?

I tried to look at the data that goes when you fill in the captcha manually. But where do I get the variables "payload", "w" and "callback"?

[image: payload captcha]

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link to solve geeTest captcha in another way ( without using 2captcha lib )

[geeTest captcha solution without 2captcha library](https://filipvitas.medium.com/how-to-solve-geetest-slider-captcha-with-js-ac764c4e9905)

Comment: It is solve for GeeTest v3.

Comment: @OttoWainenger yes, it's solved geeTest v3 captcha